# How to use the variables of a table being passed to another stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to use my table variable "@Customers"'s variables like "@Customers.Name", I have tried it  like : Customers.Name or @Customers.Name but both showing error please suggest how can i use the variables?

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableType] AS TABLE(
[CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
[City] [varchar](50) NULL,
[State] [char](2) NULL,
[Zipcode] [varchar](20) NULL
)
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetCustomers
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Customers AS TableType
INSERT INTO @Customers(CustomerID,Name,City,State,ZipCode)
SELECT C.CustomerID,C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName,A.City,A.State,A.ZipCode
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN CustomerAddress A ON C.CustomerID=A.CustomerID
EXEC sp_GetCustomersWithAddresses @Customers

END
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetCustomersWithAddresses
@Customers TableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @Customers where @Customers.Name="XYZ";
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an alias in your query. Your stored procedure should look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetCustomersWithAddresses
@Customers TableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @Customers a where a.Name='XYZ';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, you don't access table column names that way, like you might in a language like C# using classes.

But in your example, I think it's as simple as:

```
Select * From @Customers Where [Name] = 'XYZ'
```

I have 'Name' in brackets because it's a reserved word in T-SQL. And T-SQL should know that [Name] is a column because it knows that @Customers is of type TableType. So this should work.